# AWS Step Function Handle Lambda.Unknown

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a simple AWS state machine with two task states that execute C# lambda functions, and one pass state error handler to handle "States.ALL":

```
{
  "Comment": "StateMachine1",
  "StartAt": "step1",
  "States": {
    "step1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:0000:function:step1",
      "Catch": [ {
            "ErrorEquals": ["States.ALL"],
            "Next": "CatchAllFallback"
         } ],
      "Next": "step2"
    },
      "step2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:0000:function:step2",
        "Catch": [ {
            "ErrorEquals": ["States.ALL"],
            "Next": "CatchAllFallback"
         } ],
      "End": true
    },
     "CatchAllFallback": {
         "Type": "Pass",
         "Result": "This is a fallback from any error code",
         "End": true
      }
  }
}
```

When one of the steps fails, I get the following as the input to my "CatchAllFallback":

```
"Error": "Lambda.Unknown",
"Cause": "The cause could not be determined because Lambda did not return an error type."
```

When I review the Cloudwatch logs, I see that the step timed out. My question is: how do I get that information in my error handler instead of just "Lambda.Unknown"? I know it must be possible, but after spending hours searching the web, I can NOT figure out how to do it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so that this is supported by default (But maybe someone can proof me wrong?). It's because of the root of the issue. AWS Step Functions expect a valid error type to pass this to the next state but your Lambda timed out and therefore it's impossible to pass a valid error type.

**But!** You could build a workaround inside your Lambda(s).

Just check the [RemainingTime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-context-object.html) inside the `Context Object` and as soon as it is close to get timed out you throw an exception which then can be mapped to a valid error type.

> Information about the remaining time of function execution can be used
>   to specify function behavior when nearing the timeout

Comment: I wish I could prove you wrong, but I can't yet! I still haven't found a way to catch these AWS exceptions inside Lambda code. But, thanks for the hints about the context object.

Comment: I just had this same issue and, also was due to a Lambda timing out

Comment: @gvasquez did you tackle it with the race condition approach mentioned above?

Comment: @MaiKaYI had to tweak my Lambda config as it had a too low timeout for what it actually had to do

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda needs to throw the relevant error in order for the step function to give a better output, the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-exceptions.html) has an explanation for this scenario using c#

### Example

```
namespace Example {            
   public class AccountAlreadyExistsException : Exception {
      public AccountAlreadyExistsException(String message) :
         base(message) {
      }
   }
} 

namespace Example {
   public class Handler {
     public static void CreateAccount() {
       throw new AccountAlreadyExistsException("Account is in use!");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's true for exceptions that occur _within_ the C# code inside the Lambda. I'm talking about AWS-level infrastructure exceptions, for example lambda timeouts. What you outlined will not catch or handle those exceptions.